# Sort files in Terminal like finder

Tags: terminal, bash

Is it possible in the command line to have the same sort order for files/folders as Finder. If I run `find . -type d`, I get as output:

```
./Folder 1
./Folder 10
./Folder 11
./Folder 2
./Folder 3
...
```

I tried `find -s . -type d`, and also added some `sort` options. No luck.

What I want is this:

```
./Folder 1
./Folder 2
./Folder 3
...
./Folder 10
./Folder 11
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use `find` instead of `ls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at what `find` says about sorting:

```
 -s   Cause find to traverse the file hierarchies in 
lexicographical order, i.e., alphabetical order within each directory.  
Note: `find -s` and `find | sort` may give different results.
```

This means we need to pipe it to `sort` so that we can manipulate it a bit more.

As you have already seen, a simple alphanumeric sort won't work because it's comparing everything as an ANSI character not as numbers.  What we need to do is just compare the numbers.  We can do this with the `-k` option of `sort`

`find . -type d | sort -k2.3`

What the `sort -k2.3` command is doing is sorting on the second field (delimited by the space) ending at the 3rd position.  This is the result using your folder naming convention<sup>1</sup>:

```
.
./Folder 1
./Folder 2
./Folder 3
./Folder 4
./Folder 5
./Folder 6
./Folder 7
./Folder 8
./Folder 9
./Folder 10
./Folder 11
./Folder 12
./Folder 13
./Folder 14
./Folder 15
```

---

<sup>1</sup> To create this folder structure, I used the command in my home folder:

```
mkdir test; cd test; for n in {1..15}; do mkdir "Folder $n"; done
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the `-k` option. However, that didn't meet my requirements. I made [this small python program](https://gist.github.com/doekman/4f266ccfe9cb0d300e00ca73ef6cddf4) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can also do

```
ls -v
```

which sorts files by version numbers in names by natural order.

From `man ls`

```
-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Comment: macOS does not come with GNU ls installed.

Comment: GNU ls can be installed via Homebrew.